# How do you make a URL request that requires access through an ezproxy server? (Python)

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, python-requests, proxy-server

I'm doing a personal project where I am trying to scrape HTML tables from a financial data website using Python. I am able to successfully use the requests package in Python to access **public** websites and extract any information (using BeautfulSoup4 afterwards for processing), but the code I am using is shown below:

```
# import requests
import requests

# access website
url = 'https://financial-data-url.ezproxy1.library.uniname.edu.com/path/to/financial/data'
headers = example_header
page = requests.get(url, headers = headers)
```

However, trying to access the website normally requires login through my University's library database through an **EZproxy server** (shown in example url). When I attempt to request the URL of the financial data webpage after getting access through the library database, it returns what seems to be the University library EZproxy webpage. This is where I need to click "login" before being directed to the financial data webpage.

Is there some credential provision that I may be missing in the request function, or potentially a different way of passing the proxy server to the URL so that the request does not end up on the proxy server login page?

Comment: _Is there some credential provision that I may be missing in the request function_ Have you done any research? See, for example https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/authentication/.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the fastest and most effective work-around for this problem is to use the Selenium web-based automation package (https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)

Selenium makes it very easy to replicate a login as well as navigation within the browser just as a person would. IMO, the simplicity of it may far outweigh the benefits of calling the web-page directly depending on the use-case (not efficient when speed and efficiency is the primary goal, however if that is not a major constraint it works quite well)